# Google map circle not working in google Chrome border-radius overflow

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-chrome

I am making a google map in a circle shape in my footer.
I was able to make it work for Mozilla and IE but I am having problems 
with Chrome.
From the researcher I did, the problem is with border-radius not working for Chrome or overflow:hidden; Unfortunately I wasn't able to fix the problem.

Here is a link to a website, map is located in the footer.
[WEBSITE](http://www.trinaestabggim.edu.rs/novi_sajt/)

And here is my custom css for the map:

```
.custommap{
border: 5px solid #fff;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius:999px;
-moz-border-radius:999px;
-webkit-border-radius:999px;
-o-border-radius:999px;
width: 18% !important;
height: 16em !important;
}
```

Here are also images of Mozzilla and Chrome in comparison

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwuauy9y/1/) seems to work for my in Chrome, using your `.custommap`. class.

Comment: I am using wordpress, so the code excluding the css is not editable atm. So i tried to add text element and than adding html code to it. This replicates the problem i have. Here is JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/1kgpx2qt/)

Comment: you did not set the custommap class to the gmap_canvas div.

Comment: [this is the result after I did]http://jsfiddle.net/1kgpx2qt/1/

Comment: Using last JSFiddle produced even worst result.

Comment: but it's rounded. isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: here is the ps [link](http://s27.postimg.org/mhl5y7a4z/Capture.jpg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99718/discussion-between-brainiac080195-and-remdevtec).